# Search all open documents, find text, and delete to the end of the document Word Macro

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, documents

I am trying to write a vba word macro that searches all open documents, finds all occurrences of the text "DocumentEnd9999", and deletes everything below that text in each document.

```
Sub deletion()

Dim endTerm As String
endTerm = "DocumentEnd9999"

'Loop Dim
Dim n, c As Integer
n = Application.Documents.Count

For c = 1 To n
    Set myRange = Application.Documents(c).StoryRanges
    For Each myRange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = endTerm
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.Extend
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With myRange.Find
            myRange.Characters.Last.Select
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Selection.Find.Execute
        Selection.Delete
    Next myRange
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do what you're looking for in the main body of the document. Not sure exactly why you're using StoryRanges. I'm not too familiar with that collection, so I didn't include it.

```
Sub deletion()

    Dim endTerm As String
    endTerm = "DocumentEnd9999"

    Dim n, c As Integer
    n = Application.Documents.Count
    c = 1

    Dim r As Range

    Windows(c).Activate

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = endTerm
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        End With

    Do

        Selection.Find.Execute    

        Set r = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Range.Start, ActiveDocument.Content.End)
        r.Delete

        c = c + 1

        On Error Resume Next
        Windows(c).Activate

    Loop Until c > n

End Sub
```

Comment: works perfect. I used storyRanges because I don't know what I'm doing. Thanks!